# Whining sound at certain speeds

Tags: troubleshooting

My manual speed car has a whining sound that only seems to be present at certain speeds, roughly 40-50mph while cruising, doesn't seem to be rev dependant. This goes away when I press the clutch to the floor or if I put it in neutral. I don't hear it if I accelerate through this range.
It appears to be coming from the centre of the car, but I know it can be hard to pinpoint noises. Car drives, shifts gears fine otherwise. Any ideas?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! What is the year/make/model/engine/transmission type of your vehicle?

Comment: It would be good to say what make, model and year.  Some vehicles just do this.  I recall and old GMC pickup that fit this class.